# Na equação de tempo de CPU (Tcpu) o que são o número de instruções (IC) e ciclos por instrução (CPI)?

Tags: desempenho, arquitetura-computadores, cpu

De um *slide* sobre organização de computadores:

> Desempenho de instruções
>
> Um determinado programa exigirá:
>
> - um número de instruções de máquina
> - um determinado número de ciclos
> - um determinado número de segundos
>
> Assim:
>
> Tcpu = IC * CPI * Tempodociclodeclock
>
> IC = número de instruções da máquina (*instruction count*)
>
> CPI (ciclos por instrução)

Não entendi muito bem esse *slide*.

O IC é o número de instruções de máquina envolvido por exemplo em uma operação de soma ou de multiplicação (está última mais complexa que a soma). Seria o número de instruções mais básicas que compõem uma instrução de adição?

O CPI é um valor fixo, ou varia por instrução? Ou é uma média?

Ainda, não obrigatório mas se puder acrescentar, como isso tudo afeta o desempenho na execução de instruções?

Tirado [daqui](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HJirZ2sHWgM&t=12m53s), também [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FK13IR3P9M&t=36s). E [este aqui](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/3638688/course/section/835248/Desempenho%20-%20P1.pdf) também pode ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ciclo é a unidade básica de execução, é o passo mínimo de execução que ocorre e o tempo entre um e outro é definido pelo mecanismo de *clock* do computador, por isso um computador de 4Ghz executa cerca de 4 bilhões de ciclos em um segundo. I tempo entre cada um é obviamente o segundo dividido pelo número de ciclos por segundo.

A instrução é uma operação que executa algo que faça sentido para o computador e para um humano. É algo que comanda o computador a manipular dados de uma determinada forma. Pode ser um cálculo aritmético, relacional, um movimento de dados em registradores e memória, ou algo do tipo. Ele faz uma operação completa mínima.

O que eu entendi que seja o IC nesse contexto é o total de instruções de um determinado código, então estaria ensinando calcular um tempo teórico de execução.

Existem arquiteturas que todas instruções executam com a mesma quantidade de ciclos e outras onde cada instrução tem seu próprio custo, podendo até mesmo a mesma instrução variar em cada execução. Nos casos que o custo varia essa medida pode ser uma média, só não sei média de que já que depende de contexto de onde está medindo.

Imagino que essa média nesse contexto seja calculada somando a quantidade de ciclos de cada uma das instruções do código sendo observado dividindo pelo número de instruções. Porém parte da equação é multiplicar pelo número de instruções, então não deveria usar a média, deveria só usar o somatório dos ciclos. [A Wikipedia tem uma fórmula que dá para entender melhor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction).

Se não for isso não sei para que essa equação serve.

Mesmo usando a fórmula da Wikipedia pode não dar certo nas arquiteturas que a execução real acontecendo determinará quantos ciclos consumirá em determinada instrução. E dependendo do contexto pode ser pior, por uma série de otimizações que podem ocorrer. Teoria é útil, mas tem casos que ela não tem uma relação com a prática.

Eu faço muita otimização e nunca precisei fazer esse cálculo :) Precisei de outros que talvez veja nessas aulas. Pode ser que em um nível mais baixo eu precise da fórmula (da Wikipedia).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).